# Swi-Prolog asserta error

Tags: prolog, clpfd

i must assert in SWI this kind of CLP(FD) rules:

```
    asserta(schedule(A,B) :-  V = [S0,S1,S2],V ins 0..sup).
```

but i get this error:

```
    ERROR: Syntax error: Operator expected
    ERROR: asserta(schedule(A,B) :-  V = [S0,S1,S2],V 
    ERROR: ** here **
    ERROR: ins 0..sup) .
```

why? thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors here:

You need to have CLP(FD) loaded at the time when reading the text.
So there needs to be a `use_module(library(clpfd))` either as a directive like in a line

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

or entered as a goal on the toplevel. This is necessary because you are using `(ins)/2` in operator form.

The other problem is the missing parentheses. It should rather read:

```
 ..., asserta( ( schedule(A,B) :- V = [_,_,_], V ins 0..sup ) ), ...
```

As an aside, I do not think that asserting such a rule makes much sense. Dynamic databases are rarely used together with asserting rules as this one.